# Issue with QDomDocument::setContent and XML declaration attribute quotes

Tags: xml, attributes, qt5, qdomdocument

I'm having an issue when importing an XML document from a string.

The XML declaration/preprocessor has two attributes (version, encoding) which are defined within double-quotes.
However, on creating a QDomDocument via the setContent method, the double-quotes are replaced with single-quotes but only for the declaration/preprocessor element, the root element attributes still use double-quotes.

QDomDocument::toString() :

```
packet : 
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pkt uniqueID="fe87d654-dded-44e6-8c6a-70c92ebd4d7d" version="1">
 <inner uniqueID="dca0ddd7-2e91-492f-b61c-d4962a003dd9">
  <element>value</element>
 </inner>
</pkt>"
```

QDomDocument::SetContent(...) ... toString() :

```
getPacket : 
"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<pkt uniqueID="fe87d654-dded-44e6-8c6a-70c92ebd4d7d" version="1">
 <inner uniqueID="dca0ddd7-2e91-492f-b61c-d4962a003dd9">
  <element>value</element>
 </inner>
</pkt>"
```

The data is being used in a transmission protocol where on the receiving end it needs to be verified via a checksum - this verification will fail due to the conversion from double-quotes to single-quotes.

Any ideas on how I can preserve the use of double-quotes across conversion?

Thanks

See code below used to recreate the issue:

```
int main( void )
{
    QDomDocument packet = pDoc.document();
    QString stringPacket = packet.toString();
    qDebug() << "packet :" << endl << stringPacket;

    QString errorMessage; int errorLine; int errorColumn;
    QDomDocument getPacket;
    if( !(getPacket.setContent( stringPacket, &errorMessage, &errorLine, &errorColumn)) )
    {
        qDebug() << "!! error !!" << endl
                 << "message :" << errorMessage << endl
                 << "errorLine :" << errorLine << endl
                 << "errorColumn :" << errorColumn;
    }
    qDebug() << "getPacket :" << endl << getPacket.toString();
}
```

Comment: more info here http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/58504-QDomDocument-setContent-gt-toString-Double-quotes-change-to-single-quotes

Comment: You can't, since Qt programmers have done it that way, since both are valid in XML...